# How can i access files in src/main/resources dynamically when the project is a .jar or in IDE

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a project that uses files found in src/main/resources*/input* and generates files in src/main/resources*/output*.

I often used to use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources"
```

My issue with this is that it is not dynamic. It works fine when I use my IDE, but when I build my project as a .jar file, I end up having to add src/main/resources to the root where the jar is located.....which is probably bad.

I have tried using the following which returns null pointer exception

```
this.getClass().getResource("input").getPath().toString()
```

Can someone please provide me with a dynamic way to access these directories that I need that are inside src/main/resources **in a dynamic way that works from the IDE and from the .jar**?

Comment: See the documentation of [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)), it explains about using absolute versus relative resource names. And keep in mind that resources are not files and should not be accessed as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the files from resource folder using:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/NLP/models/en-lemmatizer.bin").toString();
```

NLP is a folder in resource, which in turn has a models folder with bin file inside it.

As per my knowledge, you cannot generate files or create new files inside a jar.

Comment: It's evident that any files to be created or deleted are best stored outside of /src/main/resources then, as these resources are to be packaged and not changed after packaging

Comment: @BassBoy Yes, dynamic application data should be stored in some known location external to the application. The same is true of configuration files, though it's perfectly acceptable to have the _default_ configurations embedded as a resource. Some options for where to store these files include an application-specific directory in the user home directory or a platform-specific location (e.g `%[local]appdata%` on Windows, not sure about other platforms). Basically, the take away is that resources should be considered _read-only_ assets of the application.

Comment: @ProGamer Thanks for addressing default configuration, it helped tie in the concept that the intent is to embed configurations into the packaging.